# install ROS on ubuntu 17

Tags: ros

which distribution of ROS should I install on Ubuntu 17
I have searched in [ros distributions wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) but couldn't find any specification 
and I also found that ROS Kinetic Kame is not suitable for ubuntu 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look to  [ros wiki on target platfrom](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) for each ROS distro, which was linked too in the page you cited. In your case it seems that you have a choice between Lunar and Morenia.

Then it is up to you to choose between the two based on your requirements on stability and maintainability.

Note that ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10 are not LTS, so that means that they wont' have long time support from the community and your are more likely to have to update them to a newer release in some near future to get proper support. This is usually breaking parts of your application and time consuming. That's the reason why people developing complex robotics solutions tend to stick to LTS as much as possible, so that they can do distro update every 2 years if they want the new features or keep their systems for 5 year with support.

Answer (score 0):

ROS Lunar would be geared towards that distro I believe. I ran into this issue and just rolled back to 16.04 and Kinetic.